# RecyclerView disposing items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My `RecyclerView` items contains 5 bitmaps each. I'm going to download these bitmaps during scrolling. There can be hundreds of items inside the list. I have following questions:

- How can I force `RecyclerView` to not cache off-screen items? Memory
  efficiency is top priority for me. Its ok if I would have to recreate
  items everytime they on the screen.
- Do I need to dispose off-screen items manualy(e.g. call recycle on my
  bitmaps)? If the answer is *yes*, then how can I do it?

UPD:Found how to prevent caching:

```
list.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(itemType,numCachedItems);
```

Comment: use Picasso lib https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: If `RecyclerView` will not cache of items and will recreated it every time, scrolling will as slow motion video. In general, you don't need to do anything except as using Glide or Picasso. In some specific cases, you need to do some optimization, but you didn't provide any specific information (code) in order to proceed with that.

Comment: Or your case is kind of each `RecyclerView` row contains list itself? In that case feel free to use `RecyclerView` inside `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Its something like infinite image galery where images loading dynamically when needed.Row is a simple `LinearLayout` with 5 `ImageView`s inside it.I don't want my list to cache something as I'm planning to unload images  when they're off the screen.In regular `ListView` there is `onScroll` listener where one can handle on/off screen items, but there is no such listener for `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Kamran use Picasso.
Otherwise use Glide, here is an example with bitmap conversion:

```
// load photo
Glide.with(mCtx)
     .load(url)
     .asBitmap()
     .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
         @Override
         public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                myImageView.setBitmap(resource);
            }
       });
```

This is in MyImageView (extending ImageView) on MainThread (to be authorized to alter ui)

```
@UiThread
public void setBitmap(Bitmap resource) {
    this.setImageBitmap(resource);
}
```

To disable caching you can try

```
mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0)
```

Comment: I know how to load photo from the web.The question is how can I handle (load/unload) them dynamically with`RecyclerView`

Comment: mostly how to unload them

Answer (score 0):

I just realized `RecyclerView` reuses items therefore I can unload my data within `onBindViewHolder` method